# Razorpay Integration in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, razorpay

Want to integrate the RazorPay with asp.net.My account is in Live mode. Want to know how to integrate it with asp.net step by step

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [this](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/) ? Can you be more specific what do you need? Creating a web request? Reading JSON?

Comment: i create the application to bill the item.want to pay the amount through razor pay

Comment: i read the doc file but i didn't get it...want step by step assistance